# Show Entire Width of Website on iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, css, ipad

I'd appreciate a bit of advice from someone skilled with CSS. For a reason I can't pinpoint, only the right side of my website shows up in iPhone / iPad browser, and the left 1/3rd of it can't even be seen.

If someone could explain what causes the issue and how it can be fixed, I'd be grateful.

Here's the part of css that sets the layout:

```
body {
position:absolute;
width: 960px;
top: 0px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -480px;
}
```

Comment: First, try removing the absolute positioning, width, margin, left from the BODY tag. If you want to centre your site, wrap all the content in a div width width:960px; margin: 0 auto;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Try to remove this (`position: absolute; width: 960px; top: 0px; left: 50%; margin-left: -480px;`) from your `body`.

Second: here's how to center a page `width: 960px; margin: auto`, put that on `#page`

So with the some css on `body` removed and the css below on `#page` it may work better

```
#page {
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden; /* to compensate for some element overflowing and messing up your layout */
}
```

Comment: Perfect, @Johan. This solved everything. I'm pleased to meet someone who clearly knows his way around CSS/Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

you need to modify the width of your body on every device. 
You can use @media query to do it by css

```
/*  Ipad Landscape */
@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
  body {
    width: 80%;
    left: 0%;
    margin-left: 10%;
  }

}

/* iphone 5 landscape ipad portrait */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) 
{
}

/* iphone 4 lanscape */
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) 
{
}

/* iphone 4- 5 portrait */
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) 
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Romain. Even though this is not quite what I asked about, but your suggestion will help me at the future stages of working on this project, and I very much appreciate your being so detailed about it.